# Three JS mesh color change which has vertex colors

Tags: angular, typescript, three.js

I have a problem with colors change in Three JS. I am adding meshes into my scene with vertex colors from stl files. The colors are added properly but when I try to change it via following code:

`this.meshArray[elementName].material.color.setHex( colorValue );`

The colors are not properly changed. They looks like mixture of old and new color. On the picture you can see the example. I was trying to change color of two parts to red. Gray part was changed to light red but blue one has changed to almost black. I have no idea what can be wrong with this but I assume that the problem is because i take colors from vertex colors and I don't change this setting later? Does someone know how to fix it?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're encountering this issue because you're using `vertexColors` at the same time as the `material.color` property. Each vertex has its own individual color assigned, and when applying a general material color, they multiply together, giving you undesired results. For example, blue * red = black because 255 * 0 = 0

```
0x0000ff // blue
  ****** // multiply
0xff0000 // red
0x000000 // result
```

You're going to have to either change `vertexColors` or `material.color` but not both. To access the vertex colors in the geometry, you can use the `geometry.getAttribute("color")` method, and then change each RGB value for each vertex. [See this working demo](https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_geometry_colors) for an example of the vertexColors attribute in action.

Comment: Ok, thank you for explanation. Now I am facing another problem. It works during adding the new element but when I try to dynamically change existing element by button following code doesn't work. Do you have any idea why it is not working?
`let geometry = this.scene.getObjectByName("myFile.stl").geometry 

const color = new THREE.Color(0xFF0000);

// @ts-ignore
for(let idx = 0; idx < geometry.attributes.color.count; idx++)
{
// @ts-ignore
geometry.getAttribute("color").setXYZ( idx, color.r, color.g, color.b )
}`

Comment: Please open a new question for this new issue.